# HERE maps enterprise routing api with base licence

Tags: here-api

is enterprise-routing API supported with free base license if not are there some speed limits information accesible only with base licence? I could not find these information in their docs. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed Limit information can be obtained using the `getLinkInfo` endpoint as in this example:

- [https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY](https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg).

According to  [Available Features and Functionality](http://developer.here.com/web-experiences) page, the `getLinkInfo` endpoint is not checked as being allowed with *"Limited Free Usage with Base Web Key"*. Hence you should probably enquire about an enterprise license using the get in touch button on the [Getting Started](http://developer.here.com/get-started) page